# How to launch a double tap event without the single tap event in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an image which I need to have 2 different events for, one for a single tap, another for a double tap. Problem is, if I perform a double tap on the image, on my first tap the tap event is launched, and then the double tap event is launched on my second tap (don't worry, I'm tapping fast enough!).

Is there any way to make the tap event not launch on a double tap, only on a single tap, to prevent both tap and double tap events from launching at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Dispatcher timer event to your 'Tap'

Then on your double tap event remove the dispatcher timer event associated to the single tap from the dispatcher, and run what you want the double tap action to be

Comment: I intend to do that. I don't like to have my name as 1152227. And my first name's definitely not user :P